# Dump Chrome dev console to text file?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Sometimes when I'm trying to debug an issue a user is having with my Chrome extension (StayFocusd), it would be useful to have access to the console logs. Right now I just ask them to copy-and-paste the log to me, but it would be nicer if I could programatically generate a file they could just email to me. Is that possible?

Alternately, is at least possible to capture the console contents with Javascript so I could output it to a useful debugging format for myself?

Comment: You can set up your own type of logging in your extension that supports content transmission (e.g. write to a hidden <pre> element and then dump/transmit its textContent one way or another).

Comment: But you are going to miss the error messages this way.

Answer (score 2):

There is an experimental API for that: **[chrome.experimental.devtools.console](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental.devtools.console.html)**:

```
chrome.experimental.devtools.console.getMessages(function(messages) {
    messages[0].url  // http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
    messages[0].text // XHR finished loading
    messages[0].line // 4
})
```