# How to get Chrome dev tools console logs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

**Is it possible to write all Chrome dev tools console logs to a file ?**

I was thinking of an extra argument passed to the executable or a plugin to install on the browser itself.

I would also like to avoid remote debugging as I would like to get this information for users behind a firewall.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export Javascript Console log from Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462648/export-javascript-console-log-from-google-chrome) and also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file).

Comment: ...and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311273/dump-chrome-dev-console-to-text-file

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure that writing a wrapper over console and sending the contents to my server when the page unloads will actually capture the javascript errors and traces logged by chrome. 

But I do like the answer explained here :[Dump Chrome dev console to text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311273/dump-chrome-dev-console-to-text-file) (thanks @AlexanderPavlov).